# How can I make the second and millisecond values optional in a time using a Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am reading in text files. The start of most of these files have **day-month-year hour:minute Some text here**...like the following

```
    28-09-2012 12:46 Some text here.....
```

I have written a regular expression for this

```
    (?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2})))\s(?<textFileEntry>.*)
```

This works. It reads the day, month and year separated by a hyphen **-** and the hour and minute separated by a colon **:**, then a space between using backslash s **\s**. What I want is to change the regular expression so there is the option to include seconds and milliseconds if they appear in other files in the future, like this..

```
            28-09-2012 12:46:12:123 Some text here.....
```

I have written this regular expression, but its not correct.

```
    (?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2})(?<seconds>\.?\d{2})(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3})))\s(?<textFileEntry>.*)
```

I though **.?** allowed for optional use? Can anyone see what I am missing in the regular expression? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are escaping the dot (like this `\.`) so you match the literal dot, you have just to change the dot to colon like this:

```
(?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2})(?<seconds>:\d{2})?(?<milli>:\d{0,3})?))\s(?<logEntry>.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vF4uX7/1)**

Also notice I added `?` to set your seconds and milli as optional:

```
(?<seconds>:\d{2})?(?<milli>:\d{0,3})?
                  ^-- here and here -^
```

Btw, if you really want to use the `.` as wildcard, then any character can be used as a second/mill separator.

You can see below the pattern clearly:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @NepSyn14 if my answer solved your question you might consider marking your question as solved :)

Comment: Ok. How do i do that?

Comment: @NepSyn14 In each answer below the vote quantity you will see a check. Just click on the check for the answer you consider solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` matches exactly one character unless you escape it (which you did) and in that case it only matches the character `.`.

Furthermore, if you want to make an entire group optional, use `(:(?<milli>\d{0,3}))?`, so an asteriks after the whole parathesis that you wish to make optional.

Answer (score 0):

Fede has it almost right, but his regex catches the colon : char in the seconds and milliseconds - use this https://regex101.com/r/bU9bJ6/1

```
(?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}))(:\:?(?<seconds>\d{2})?)?\:?(?<mili>\d+)?)\s(?<logEntry>.*)
```